# How to align two images on the same line without space in between with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I have two images that I would like to place on the same line with bootstrap.

This is image one
[image: Image 1]

And this is Image two

[image: Image two]

Basically what I want to achieve with bootstrap is this
[image: WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE]

This the code I have used so far

```
<div class="row"> 


<div class="col-md-12">
<img name="iimajinnewworkedon_r4_c1" src="http://i.imgur.com/Fkg67Ng.jpg" width="815" height="456" id="iimajinnewworkedon_r4_c1" alt=""  class="img-responsive"/>


</div>


<div class="col-md-4">

<img src="http://i.imgur.com/iKa3nvy.jpg" width="465" height="456"  alt=""  class="img-responsive"/>
   </div>

</div>
```

Problem :
When i use that code, instead of displaying the images on the same line without space, it displays the two images but with a wide space between them.

[image]

How do i remove the space between the two images ?

> [A demo of my code can be seen here](http://usefaith.voiedusucces.net/brouillons.php) and [a Jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/kressly/79feLhek/9/)

Comment: One row in bootsrap is 12 columns long. You should change your div class values so their sum would be 12, for example first class: col-md-7 and second class: col-md-5.

Comment: and you should probably use col-xs because this will set the others (think small to big), col-md won't touch col-xs and col-sm

Comment: @fsn No the first row is 8 and the second is 4 and all together makes 12. Please check the JsFiddle. And even when i changed it to 7 and 5 like you mentionned it is still doing the same thing

Comment: @maraca It works perfectly when it comes to small devices. With small devices, it goes back down the other one and i am ok with that . But on pc, it does not align on the same line and that is my problem. If you think i can solve that with col-xs please kindly let me know how to. Tks

Comment: @ManOfGod no in this case it is ok, then col-xs and col-sm are just 12.

Comment: @maraca so do you have a solution for my problem ?

Comment: Did none of the answers work? you might need to reset margin and padding for container, row and col... but maybe only for md size and maybe only for this container, can be done with @media , see bootstrap's own stylesheet.

Answer (score 2):

I had almost the same case, and was able to solve it by modifying padding values.

In your case, the solution would be by;

1. Change **col-md-12** to **col-md-8** (Bootstrap grid 12 cols = width 100%)
2. image tag (img) should not have **width** and **height** attributes
3. Modify padding values.

**Corrected HTML**

```
<div id="unique-name" class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <img name="iimajinnewworkedon_r4_c1" src="http://i.imgur.com/Fkg67Ng.jpg" id="iimajinnewworkedon_r4_c1" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/iKa3nvy.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
</div>
```

**Add the below to your CSS file**

```
#unique-name img {
    padding-left:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
    /* Modifiying the below lines would help you achieve same height for the 2 columns */
    /*padding-top: 5px;*/
    /*padding-bottom: 5px;*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your class values, to their int sum match 12 as it's bootstrap grid column count.

As @maraca said experiment with col-xs and col-sm.

Use firebug or smthing similiar to see what makes your div's tick.

Comment: The sum of my class are already 12 (8+4). I have firebug but i do not seem to know why there is that space. Please kindly visit http://usefaith.voiedusucces.net/brouillons.php and look down and let me know whether you are able to identify why i am having that space there

Comment: mate do empty place holder <div class="col-md-2"> before you divs, make them 6 and 4 for, or better make place holder 2 then div 4 and div 4 then 2. And rescale your graphic to be equal size. The problem is that your img ins`t filling whole dive. The divs itself are placed correctly, try to give them border and see it yourself.

Comment: yes I have checked it and that is exactly my problem. How to remove those white space in between the images and have the two images on the same line ? Can you help me out with that ?

Comment: Make the images fill 100% or just align them right and left instead of center. Or make child divs into those divs and push them into the middle  from left and right side.

Comment: it did not work for me but thanks for the solid border. It helped me to find out what was going on. +1

Answer (score 0):

You need add padding:0 to the columns to remove the gap.

Comment: I did that but it did not remove it. You can see it here http://usefaith.voiedusucces.net/brouillons.php

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap.min.css is applying padding to the col-md-x class.

```
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
```

Add a new class that overrides it

```
<div class="col-md-8 your-new-class">
```

CSS:

```
.your-new-class{
    padding-left:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
}
```

And then it looks like there is an image border that you need to remove in a similar way. These should be in a separate .css file that is referenced after bootstrap.

Comment: I did that but still nothing changed. You can check it at   http://usefaith.voiedusucces.net/brouillons.php